# Invitation Listener not working smack 4.2

Tags: android, openfire, smack, multiuserchat

I can create group chat room successfully XMPP(smack). I have added
        invitation listener, but never called.   Does anyone know how to do it?

### Using:

1. XMPP
2. Smack 4.2
3. Openfire server

### Send Invitation code:

```
 muc.invite(userId +"@" +XMPP.getInstance().HOST + "/Smack", "Meet me in this excellent room");
```

### Invitation listener code:

```
         MultiUserChatManager manager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
            manager.addInvitationListener(new InvitationListener() {
                @Override
                public void invitationReceived(XMPPConnection xmppConnection, MultiUserChat muc, String inviter, String reason, String password, Message message) {
                    try {
                        muc.join(nickname);
                    } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have an issue about `RESOURCE`.

When you send an invitation to a certain *JID*, you might omit *resource* part or the message will be sent only to specified *resource*.

JID it's composed in following way:

```
user@serverdomain/resource
```

With this invitation, you are inviting only user using "**Smack**" as *Resource*.
*Resource* it's configurated in `AbstractXMPPConnection` object or in *login* phase

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                .setServiceName(serverName)
                .setHost(server)
                .setPort(port)
                .setResource( RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)
                .build();
connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);

connection.login(username, password, RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER);
```

So, probably, you declared as your resource identificator (just an arbitrary String) not "Smack" but "Spark" o something else or left default one.

Just omit Resource part (or fix with correct one, but I suggest to omit)

```
 muc.invite(userId +"@" +XMPP.getInstance().HOST, "Meet me in this excellent room");
```

*Of course, userId must exist and HOST it's the valid one*

Comment: Thank you very much dear MrPk . Now code is working.